# CW-approximation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Paul Selick's book  *Introduction to Homotopy Theory*, he says that one can prove the CW-Approximation Theorem:

> Given a topological space $Y$ there exists CW-complex $X$ and a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f_\ast : \pi_n(X) \rightarrow \pi_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism for all $n$.

using the fact that

> Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a map between CW-complex. Then there exists $g : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $g \simeq f$ and $g$ is cellular.

However he does not give any detail and I don't see how one should proceed.

Comment: Paul Selick's book is very concise. It it not really a good "introduction". I would recommend considering another book for a learner. For example, Hatcher's text, which covers CW approximation on pg 352. (Personally I dislike Hatcher's style, but his book still comes highly recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

In Hatcher in his book available here : http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf describes "cellular approximation" that results in theorem 4.8 page 349, which is what you want to prove.

As usual with CW-complexes, this is prove by induction on the $n$-dimensional skeletons.  The details can be quite complex depending on what you already know true about CW-complexes or not, I'm letting you read the text and ask another question if you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know the proof of Hatcher's book. What I am really wondering is how to get the result from this proposition, as a "second proof" if you wish.